# Open link when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have these buttons to which I would like to add link for redirect:

```
<Tooltip title="Open New Ticket">
  <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
    <AddTwoToneIcon />
  </IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

I added this:

```
<Tooltip title="Open New Ticket">
 <Link to='open-ticket'>
  <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
    <AddTwoToneIcon />
  </IconButton>
 </Link>
</Tooltip>
```

But when I press the button I'm not redirected to a new page. This button for example is working fine:

```
                            <Link to='open-ticket'>
                                <Button
                                    variant="contained"
                                    color="primary"
                                    size="small"
                                    startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
                                >
                                    Open Ticket
                                </Button>
                            </Link>
```

Do you know what is the proper way to implement this functionality?

Comment: Try to inspect the rendered html. Do you see any `<a>` tag there?

Comment: Check if you're using the `Link` component from [MUI](https://mui.com/components/links/#main-content) or from `react-router`

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to a different path in the same web app, or trying to open a link to a different domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your button you can add:

onClick={event =>  window.location.href='/your-href'}

Comment: Is there a better way?

Comment: Wouldn't this make another HTTP call and reload all the sources of react-app again? 
This practice should be highly criticized.

Comment: @HamzaAsif My first thought was that the link was an external link eg. www.google.com that is why i said that, if we are talking about an internall link there are for sure better ways to do it like `history.push(path);` Inside the OnClick {}

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have installed `react-router-dom`. `@material-ui/core/Link` will not work.
2. Import `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` and wrap your root component within.

```js
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import Root from "./views/Routes";
...
const App = props => {
 return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Root />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

3. In your `Root` component, specify the `Route`s with `path` and `render` component and wrap them inside `Switch` component. `Switch` enforces that only one of the `Route` children are matched. The URL is evaluated against `Route` components inside `Switch` and the first `Route` component whose `path` is a prefix-match of URL, is rendered. That is why you have to be careful of the order of `Route` components inside `Switch`

```js
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./Main";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import NotFound from "./404";

const Root = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Main />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about" render={(p) => <About {...p} />} />
        <Route path="/404" render={(p) => <NotFound {...p} />} />
        <Route path="/" render={(p) => <Home {...p} />} />
        <Redirect to="/404" />
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
export default Root;
```

4. Use `Link` from `react-router-dom`

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Tooltip, IconButton, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { HomeTwoTone, InfoTwoTone } from "@material-ui/icons";
const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2} justifyContent="center">
      <Grid item>
        <Tooltip title="Home Page">
          <Link to="/">
            <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
              <HomeTwoTone />
            </IconButton>
          </Link>
        </Tooltip>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Tooltip title="About Page">
          <Link to="/about">
            <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
              <InfoTwoTone />
            </IconButton>
          </Link>
        </Tooltip>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default Main;
```

Here is a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-northcutt-0w7ck)